# Show and Hide a field in UI component Form

Tags: magento2, dynamic-rows

I want to show and hide a dynamic field in custom UI form based on radio button selection. Can I perform this functionality using magento2 or I have to use Javascript / Jquery for that ?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I cannot do this in the way like we use switcher config ?

Comment: We can show hide a field in ui form based on switcher config ( yes /no ) , In the same way can we implement the same functionality on radio button selection without usig javascript / Jquery

Comment: you can do that by extending default components  i did in one on the extension you can check that one https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-product-slider-extension.html

Comment: You can try via linking properties in ui components checkout this official link of magento - https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/concepts/linking/